# "Last Import" in Photos shows 1,000s of photos, not just last import

Tags: macos, photos

The "Last Import" function of Photos seems stuck.  It shows all my photos from Feb, 2012 - Feb, 2017.  Which is really strange, as I import photos from my phone about once a week.  I.e., I'm imported dozens of times since Feb, 2017.

How do I reset/fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try rebuilding your Photos Library. However, **ensure you have a backup** of your Photos Library (e.g. a Time Machine backup) **before** rebuilding the library!

To rebuild the library, follow these steps:

- Make sure that Photos is **not** running
- While holding down the <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd> keys, launch the Photos app
- The *Repair Library* window should appear
- Click on <kbd>Repair</kbd> to rebuild your photo library

Depending on the size of your library, this may take some time.

Comment: Read the whole thing, because the warnings come after the spell?

Comment: @DonielF Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry. Doctor Strange reference.

Comment: Oh! Okay. But I think I see what you were getting at now - I've edited my answer to put the _warning_ before the steps! Thanks for the feedback. :)